# How to change header font and nav link color when slideshow image changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header and I have a slideshow just behind it. Basically the header has a transparent background and it's just text over the slideshow. Now I'm trying to change the color of my header font(which includes my nav) color when the image of my slider changes. The problem I'm having is that my slider is purely CSS3 and I can't find a way to detect when the image is being changed to change my header font.

Here's my code for my slider:
**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/eg1.jpg" alt="" class="imageA">
        <img src="images/eg2.jpg" alt="" class="imageB">
        <img src="images/eg3.jpg" alt="" class="imageC">        
    </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

div#slider { 
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 100vh; 
}
div#slider figure img {
    width: 50%; 
    float: left;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background:cover;
}
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 15s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Here's my Header HTML. I don't think the CSS is needed but if needed let me know I'll put it here:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <h2>The Market</h2>
    </div>

    <nav id="headNav">
        <ul>
            <li data-menuanchor="home" class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <span>|</span>
            <li data-menuanchor="collections"><a href="#collections">Collections</a></li>
            <span>|</span>
            <li data-menuanchor="showroom"><a href="#showroom">Showroom</a></li>
            <span>|</span>
            <li data-menuanchor="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <span>|</span>
            <li data-menuanchor="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Finally here's the javascript I used to change the header text color when the image changes. It doesn't work but it's what I tried. I would really appreciate any help on how to fix the script:

```
<script>
    $('img.imageA').on('load',function(){
        document.getElementById("header").style.color = "red";
    });
</script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You use keyframes for moving slider, so use the same breakpoints in another keyframes with the same animation duration, but in this keyframes change color/bg/etc for any element you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easy solution would be to use the same animation timing for changing     the color of text,try this:

```
header{animation : 15s colorful}
@keyframes colorful {
0% {  color:blue}
20% { color:blue}
25% { color:purple}
45% { color:purple}
50% { color:purple}
70% { color:purple}
75% { color:pink}
95% { color:pink}
100% { color:cyan}
}
```

Comment: I tried it but for some reason it breaks the slider and the latter stops working. Edit: I realized I had a bracket missing. This works perfect. Thanks :_)

Comment: Oh sorry, I tested it and I realized the effect applies along the whole page. However I want it to apply only to the slider. Is that possible?

Comment: I added animation to header selector , but you can try to hook it up to `ǹav`

Comment: Yes exactly. On applying it to a nav, it works fine and same for the header. However When I scroll to another section on the page which is no longer a slider, it gets messed up since the color keeps changing on the header and nav which are both position: fixed;

Comment: since it's fixed that's normal behaviour